# Occam's razor obsolete?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I saw Vapnik's books about statistical learning... I read the first few chapters.
Anyway what surprised me the most was that he thought that the Occam's razor was obsolete.

I thought it was related to the situation in which assuming higher dimension improves the fit significantly.

Am I understood right? Is it correct that Occam's razor can't be no longer right like Vapnik said?

Is there any argument that Occam's razor shouldn't be considered as the default?

The exact sentences come from the Preface to the Second Edition of [The Nature of Statistical Learning](http://books.google.fr/books/about/The_Nature_of_Statistical_Learning_Theor.html?id=sna9BaxVbj8C), which are:

> The years since the first edition of the book have also changed the general
>   philosophy in our understanding the of nature of the induction problem.
>   After many successful experiments with SVM, researchers became more
>   determined in criticism of the classical philosophy of generalization based
>   on the principle of Occam's razor."

I wish someone could elaborate on the criticism on Occam's razor.

Comment: It might be not related. Read about Simplicity does not imply accuracy, in A Few Useful Things to Know about Machine Learning by Domingos.

Comment: It might help if you could give a page reference, so Vapnik's comment can be seen in context.

Comment: I added the excerpt from the second edition of the Nature of Statiatical Learning to the question.

Answer (score 10):

Depends on what you consider to be the "Occam's razor"; the original formulation is an unclear theological mumbo-jumbo, so it flourished into a bunch of (often incompatible) interpretations.

Vapnik criticizes the ultranaive version saying more less that a model with lower number of fitted parameters is better because too much parameters imply overfitting, i.e. something in the melody of the [Runge's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon).
It is of course false in machine learning because the "greedyness of fitting" there is not constrained by the number parameters but (via some heuristic) by the model accuracy on the future data.

But does it mean that ML training is introducing plurality without necessity? I would personally say no, mainly due to the second part -- ML models are usually better than hand-razored classical regressions, so this extra complexity pays off. Even if it can be reduced by a human to a simpler theory, this almost always come for a price of extra assumptions, so it is not a fair comparison.